Remembering Mouse clicks - Is there any theory behind it?
As everyone of you must be using computer systems from long time now, I want to get your insights on mouse click remembrance(I don't know the exact term).
Whenever I have used mac or windows, sometimes say when there is too much of load on the processor due to background processes etc, usually the systems slows down. Assume in some cases very short lag may be about 2 seconds. I have performed clicks like lets say windows refresh on windows(I am sure we all have done it).
I want to know if there is any UX strategy with a feature like this where the systems remembers upto 3 clicks or so and performs it in the same sequence once the system picks up the processing speed.

It's not a planned feature which might have a UX intention behind it. It's just a side effect of the software architecture. Clicks are performed on the UI layer, the signal is transmitted to be processed, the software reacts and sends the signal to the monitor, where we see the output. What you're describing is a bottleneck somewhere along the way, which causes a delay in this process, causing the corresponding actions to be performed later, when the system "gets around to it". It's not something that's been deliberately designed to work this way.

Interesting ! ! Thank you @Vitaly
